# Notepad++ Replacing Text Between Two Strings

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, notepad

I'm trying to remove strings between two words in .po file. Tried few things already fish search&replace but so far it didn't go well.

Example of text:

```
msgctxt ",0CAEC952474D390ED3EACB814418BE9A"
msgid ""
"Captain Thorus needs \r\n"
"all men attend him"
msgstr ""
"Kapitan Thorus potrzebuje \r\n"
"wszystkich przy sobie"
```

And I would like to replace:

```
msgid ""
"Captain Thorus needs \r\n"
"all men attend him"
```

With just blank field \n. But the thing is that msgid "" can contain custom texts like msgid "some_text" and text below also are different.

Is there a way to just  replace everything between msgctxt "" and msgstr "" to blank?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try:

```
(?s)msgctxt.*?\"$\K.*?(?=msgstr)
```

The above regex resulted in after substitution:

```
msgctxt ",0CAEC952474D390ED3EACB814418BE9A"
msgstr ""
"Kapitan Thorus potrzebuje \r\n"
"wszystkich przy sobie"
```

Comment: It works 50/50.

It search for values but is not able to replace with anything. After clicking "replace" it's just jumping forward.

Comment: Ok - weird. It doesn't work with single "replace" but with "replace all" it works! :)

Comment: Done! Thanks! Really thank you!